# Foreign key integrity violation

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I have two tables and there is a foreign key. Although I have defined conditions `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE`, when I delete a row from the `BENEFIT` table, I get an `integrity error`.

The error is documented below:

> psycopg2.IntegrityError
>
> psycopg2.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "benefit" violates foreign key constraint "people_hasbenefit_fkey" on table "people"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (benef)=(improving intelligence) is still referenced from table "people".

The tables are like below:

```
"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS benefit (
                    ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
                    Benef text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                    Type text NOT NULL)"""


 """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
                        Peopleid serial PRIMARY KEY,
                        Name text NOT NULL,
                        HasBenefit text references benefit(Benef)
                        ON DELETE SET NULL
                        ON UPDATE SET NULL )"""
```

Comment: Using TEXT as a foreign key is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Probably impossible, since you cannot `INDEX` a `TEXT` column.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue Javid?   Getting the same similar quirk here.